# Excel in Cell Function VALUE for Formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel sheet which I need to run on Android. Only problem, I used VBA for the Evaluate Function and VBA does not work on Android Apps. I was searching for an alternative and came a round the function "VALUE()", I saw that a Cell with:

```
=VALUE(10 + 5 * 3)
```

Would return the correct result (25).
Now what I would like to do is:

```
=VALUE(A2)
```

Where A2 is a text containing "10 + 5 * 3".
But this returns "#VALUE!"

Is there a trick how i could use VALUE() to evaluate simple formulas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid its not possible to evaluate text as formula without VBA.

Comment: is the function "VALUE()" not doing this? In my first example it takes a formula and prints the result, the only thing that is missing is how to use a cell instant of writing the formul in the VALUE(...)

Comment: "is the function "VALUE()" not doing this?" No, it is not. `VALUE()` is a type conversion.

Answer (score 3):

There is a hack that has been around for years that does this in the full version of Excel. I doubt it will work on Android but it may be worth trying.

I'm using Excel 2013.

Go to the FORMULAS ribbon bar and choose Define Name.

Give any name, for example `myResult`

In the "Refers to:" part, put the formula `=EVALUATE(A2)`

Now, put the formula `=myResult` in your sheet where you want the answer to appear.

Comment: Already found this solution, and no dont work on Android :( Thanks anyway

Comment: Hmm, didn't think it would to be honest but worth a try anyway. I'm afraid you are out of luck then. `Value()` only evaluates a number written as text not a formula.

Answer (score 1):

Use INDIRECT().

Example (from [Microsoft Office INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)):

```
Data
B2     1.333
B3     45
George 10
5      62
```

```
Formula            Description                                                  Result
'=INDIRECT(A2)     Value of the reference in cell A2. The reference is to       1.333
                   cell B2, which contains the value 1.333.                                   
'=INDIRECT(A3)     Value of the reference in cell A3. The reference is to          45
                   cell B3, which contains the value 45.
'=INDIRECT(A4)     Because cell B4 has the defined name "George," the reference to 10
                   that defined name is to cell B4, which contains the value 10
'=INDIRECT("B"&A5) Combines "B" with the value in A5, which is 5. This, in turn,   62
                   refers to cell B5, which contains the value 62.
```

> <sub>Applies To: Excel 2016, Excel 2010, Excel Starter, Excel 2013, Excel Online, Excel 2016 for Mac, Excel for Mac 2011, Excel 2007</sub>

Comment: It's OK to use an example from an official source in an answer as long as you provide a link along with it to show where it came from.

Comment: @Karel, thanks for the beautiful edit. How did you get on to me that I stole this from MS? :)

Comment: Purely by accident, after reading your answer I searched for documentation about the Excel INDIRECT function and that link came out near the top of the Google search results.

Comment: @karel You mean you actually searched in google to get the information you needed instead of just asking someone? LIFEHACK! :D

Comment: It isn't clear how this accomplishes what was asked in the question.  Can you add an example that shows how to convert a text formula, like 10 + 5 * 3, to a calculated result (25) using INDIRECT?

Answer (score -1):

There IS a "trick" to doing so.

I assume you mean you'd like to evaluate a simple formula like the one used in your `VALUE()` formula:  10 + 5 * 3  rather than a version literally surrounded by quotes. But even if you were not using the usual convention to show the thing of interest inside quotes and really would present the string to evaluate in the cell with the quotes, well, that can be done too.

And VERY simply.

To do what I believe you wish to do:  say cell A1 has the content:  `10 + 5 * 3`. You consider where you intend your output to go relative to cell A1 and select that desired cell. So, if you want the output in cell C1, select C1. While so selected, create a Named Range, perhaps called TextCalculate, and give it the following formula for its `Refers to` value:

```
=EVALUATE(A1)
```

Close that up and in cell C1 enter:

```
=TextCalculate
```

and it will evaluate whatever is in A1 as you desire (IF it can:  It has to be something that Excel can make sense of!) and show the result in cell C1.

If you really would have quotes around the input, it's as simple as setting up another Named Range for that kind of input data and give it the value of:

```
=EVALUATE(EVALUATE(A1))
```

The first `EVALUATE()` strips off the quotes, then the second evaluates the clean remaining string.

Notice I said put the function **IN A NAMED RANGE** rather than saying put it directly in a cell. This is an absolute must, no screwing around, and if you try this and it doesn't work, you probably tried it cell-side anyway. Do it IN A NAMED RANGE and it WILL work.

Why is that? Well, that's interesting though I think from your question you know why already... but others reading may not (hence the following and the surely unneeded by you admonishments about only trying it in Named Ranges). The function is from the set of commands Excel used for building macros before VBA was implemented. It is designed for use in macros built using the old tools and the only place in Excel itself those still work is in the Named Range functionality. Note that they never, any of them, ever worked outside macros and they don't today either:  except inside a Named Range.

As long as the Android version can use Named Ranges, it may work there. Honestly, I cannot check that and believe it may not as my best GUESS is the Android version is a rewrite, not a port, and they might've ditched this aspect of Excel, especially since it was for macros and you find Android won't do those. However, since it is not part of VBA itself, just is accessible to it, it could be they ported and it came along though they did not build in an interface to VBA (nor, I would therefore assume, to anything else either). So try `EVALUATE()` in a Named Range in Android Excel and see. It may indeed not have been brought along, but then again, it might've. Not as a tool for VBA, obviously, but still maybe available to Named Ranges.

Gotta test something before stopping... bummer... the names used in `LET()` seem very much like Named Ranges "scoped" to the individual formula (they seem like it in general and will supercede an actually defined Named Range so...), and I wondered if it would work in the formula for a name used in `LET()`. Alas though, it did not... Must be more (or less) to it.

Comment: This solution is already proposed and confirmed not working.